# Certificate Authentication 403 Access Denied

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, .net-core, client-certificates

We created the service that require  client certificate for auth. The server  take the certificate, verify  and generate JWT token. Technology  is **.net core**.
**The Problem is** when  the client press the cancel button on certificate selection, next time when he tries he gets 403 access denied and certificate selection didn't appear.
I found some services on the internet that works  ok. On each request certificate selection window appears. But their  services is written in different technology (java   :  server APACHE).

**The Code  is here  :**
**Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            BuildConfiguration();

            XmlConfigurator.Configure(LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()), new FileInfo("log4net.config"));

            X509Certificate2 certificate = GetServiceCertificate(Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting")["SSlCertname"], Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting")["SSLCertPassw"]);
            IHostBuilder whb = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(o =>
                {
                    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(o =>
                o.ClientCertificateMode =
                    ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate);
                });

                webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Convert.ToInt32(Configuration.GetSection("AppSetting")["PortNumber"])), listenOptions =>
                    {
                        var httpsConnectionAdapterOptions = new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions()
                        {
                            ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate,
                            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12,
                            ServerCertificate = certificate
                            //,
                            //ServerCertificateSelector= (connectionContext, name) =>
                            //{
                            //    return null ;
                            //}
                        };
                        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsConnectionAdapterOptions);
                        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1;
                    });
                });
            });

            return whb;
        }

 public static void Main(string[] args) => CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
    {

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        protected readonly ILog _logger;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.InstallServicesAssembly(Configuration);
            services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(options =>
           {
               options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.Chained;
               options.RevocationFlag = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
               options.RevocationMode = System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
               options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
               {
                   OnCertificateValidated = async (context) =>
                   {
                       _logger.Info($"/n--------Certificate Validation Process start --------/n");

                       if (context.ClientCertificate == null)
                       {
                           context.Success();
                            //context.Fail("Certificate is null");
                            return;
                       }
                       Console.WriteLine("Validation Start");

                       ContainerResult<ValidateCertificateOutput> data = await context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                       .GetService<ICertificateValidationService>().ValidateCertificate(new ValidateCertificateInput
                       {
                           LoginCertificate = context.ClientCertificate
                       });

                       if (!data.IsSuccess)
                       {
                           context.Fail(data.ErrorList[0].ErrorMessage);
                           _logger.Error($"{data.ErrorList[0].ErrorMessage}");
                           return;
                       }
                       context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(data.Output.CertificateClaims, context.Scheme.Name));

                       _logger.Info($"Success Data : {data.Output.CertificateClaims[0].Value}");
                       _logger.Info($"/n--------Certificate Validation Process End --------/n");
                       context.Success();

                   },
                   OnAuthenticationFailed = async (context) =>
                   {

                   }


               };
           });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCertificateForwarding();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
        }
    }
```

**NOTE:**

> For solving the second attempt  problem we need to close  the browser and open again.

For more information about this issue a made  some research with comparing my service  with  worked other service   on the internet.

That is the results.
**MY Service**

**1. Curl verbose response:**

```
 curl --insecure -v https://myservice.com:4530/api/v1/certificate/login?origin=http://test.com
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying [*.*.*.*]:4530...
* Connected to myservice.com ([*.*.*.*]) port 4530 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: D:/Dev/Git/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [100 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [4571 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
{ [30 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
} [7 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.myservice.com
*  start date: Apr 13 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: May  9 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=Sectigo Limited; CN=Sectigo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /api/v1/certificate/login?origin=http://test.com HTTP/1.1
> Host: myservice.com:4530
> User-Agent: curl/7.69.1
> Accept: */*
>
{ [5 bytes data]
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Wed, 17 Mar 2021 11:32:03 GMT
< Server: Kestrel
< Content-Length: 0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
<
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Connection #0 to host myservice.com left intact
```

**2. Other Working service**

```
$ curl --insecure -v https://otherservice.com:5543/digital-login/digital-login
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying [*.*.*.*]:5543...
* Connected to otherservice.com ([*.*.*.*]) port 5543 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: D:/Dev/Git/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [97 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5529 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [300 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
{ [362 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
} [7 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [37 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
{ [2 bytes data]
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Comment: What version of Net? Is config file set for using Net or Windows for TLS?  Starting in Net 4.7.2 there is an option for using Windows or Net for the TLS.  You should be using windows.  Then make sure the kernel of mobile devices are update to work with TLS 1.2.

Comment: @jdweng I am using .net core  3.1 .  I tested in both  IIS  and the kestrel . But the result is the same. As you can see  the Transport protochol is TLS1.2

Comment: The issue is not the server.  Even though you are using Core 3.1 the version of Net is important.  With Net 4.7.2 you can target different version of Net/Core and for the targeting to always work you need Net 4.7.2 or later.  You also need to know if you are using Net or the operating System for TLS.  The best way of going is to use the operating system and make sure if mobile that your kernel is up to date.  With TLS there is a certificate block hat is sent from server to client with a list of certificate names.  the certificate has to be loaded in the client stores for both user and machine.

Comment: @jdweng  i dont understand. Endpoint client  is  PC  Browsers  (chrome , opera , edge   ...etc . Except Firefox) I am using .net core in the server . And the issue is closely related to the server. Because in the same PC i  test  both API  .   My  API didn't work correctly .  But the second works  Ok.

Comment: @Freeedy did you find answer on your question?